# SQL Server : return multiple values from function

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to return multiple values from a function? Ideally looking to do something along these lines (I know that syntax is wrong!)

```
SELECT 
    1 as test1, 2 as test2, 3 as test3, 
    fn_result(test1, test2, test3)[0] as result1, 
    fn_result(test1, test2, test3)[1] as result2, 
    fn_result(test1, test2, test3)[2] as result3

FUNCTION fn_result(val1, val2, val3) 
   RETURN (val1 + val2, val2 + val3, val1 + val3)
```

I have no experience at all with SQL functions so not sure if such a thing can be done.

Thanks

Comment: You want a [table-valued function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: well you could return a table-valued function, or an XML document, but you're using a scalar-valued function syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Use `inline table valued function` with `cross apply`:

```
Create function fn_result(@val1 int, @val2 int, @val3 int)
returns table
as
Return (select @val1+@val2 as val12,
@val1+@val3 as val13, @val2+@val3 as val23)
go

select * from (select 1 as test1, 2 as test2, 3 as test3) t
cross apply dbo.fn_result(t.test1, t.test2, t.test3)
```

Output:

```
test1   test2   test3   val12   val13   val23
1       2       3       3       4       5
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/857c1/3

Comment: (select * from dbo.fn_result(t.test1, t.test2, t.test3)) is redundant.
 I would use only dbo.fn_result(t.test1, t.test2, t.test3)

Comment: How is it redundant? It returns set. Try in fiddle

Comment: It is redundant because you can write the same query like this:
select * from (select 1 as test1, 2 as test2, 3 as test3) t
cross apply dbo.fn_result(t.test1, t.test2, t.test3) ca  Imo it is cleaner with one less level of nesting which does not offer anything.